# Am i doing something wrong with the loops?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am using python to do some data cleaning and i've used the datetime module to split date time and tried to create another column with just the time.

My script works but it just takes the last value of the data frame.

Here is the code:

```
import datetime

i = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(df.iloc[i, 0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    df['minutes'] = date.minute 
    i = i + 1
```

This is the dataframe  :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVQsA.png)

Answer (score 3):

`df['minutes'] = date.minute` reassigns the entire `'minutes'` column with the scalar value `date.minute` from the last iteration.

You don't need a loop, as 99% of the cases when using pandas.

You can use vectorized assignment, just replace `'source_column_name'` with the name of the column with the source data.

```
df['minutes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['source_column_name'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').dt.minute
```

It is also most likely that you won't need to specify `format` as `pd.to_datetime` is fairly smart.

Quick example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['2020.1.13', '2019.1.13']})
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a']).dt.year
print(df)
```

outputs

```
           a  year
0  2020.1.13  2020
1  2019.1.13  2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to get the time column from the datetime which is in string format. That's what I understood from your post.
Could you give this a shot?

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def get_time(date_cell):
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_cell, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    return datetime.strftime(dt, "%H:%M:%SZ")

df['time'] = df['date_time'].apply(get_time)
```